# Eclipse: Send Builder messages to specific Console

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

My Eclipse-CDT project has several Builders. The log messages from these builders are all sent to their own (temporary) console which immediately after starting the next Builder disappears (forever). Is there a way to send these messages to one specific console, e.g. the CDT Global Build console (or any other console)?